# Spring Support IntellIJ

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, jhipster

I followed the instruction on https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-idea/ to configure my IntellIJ. Unfortunately, IntellIJ doesn't offer the normal Spring configuration anymore. Which one do I have to choose?

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html

Comment: Thanks! I did a refresh and saw that it's already included.